# Three buttons(span's), jQuery IF clicked, addClass - removeClass

Tags: jquery, mootools

I have three buttons (spans) that looks like this:

```
<span id="size_default"><?php echo JText::_('VIDEO_DEFAULT');?></span>
<span id="size_450"><?php echo JText::_('VIDEO_450');?></span>
<span id="size_600"><?php echo JText::_('VIDEO_600');?></span>
```

These are supposed to work like buttons, and they work now, but not correctly, what I need is, when for example "size_600" is cliked, 2 actions must occur ->

```
<span id="size_600">
```

must get a "active" class + remove the "active" class on other 2 spans if they were clicked before AND then add a class to OTHER div and remove other classes that are related to the other 2 spans...

The description I made may look confusing, but here is the jQuery code I wrote, this should be more clear:

```
        $('size_default').addEvent('click',function(){
        $('size_default').addClass('active');
            $('youtube-player').addClass('h_355');
            $('size_450').removeClass('active');
            $('size_600').removeClass('active');
            $('youtube-player').removeClass('h_450');
            $('youtube-player').removeClass('h_600');
        });
        $('size_450').addEvent('click',function(){
        $('size_450').addClass('active');
            $('youtube-player').addClass('h_450');
            $('size_355').removeClass('active');
            $('size_600').removeClass('active');
            $('youtube-player').removeClass('h_355');
            $('youtube-player').removeClass('h_600');
        });
        $('size_600').addEvent('click',function(){
        $('size_600').addClass('active');
            $('youtube-player').addClass('h_600');
            $('size_355').removeClass('active');
            $('size_450').removeClass('active');
            $('youtube-player').removeClass('h_355');
            $('youtube-player').removeClass('h_450');
        });
```

Currently it "does" it's work when you click ONE time for each 3 spans(buttons), but after that only the first block of jQuery code works (size_default)...

Can somebody give me a hand on this please.. I'm not to good in jQuery...

Thank you

Comment: Is this jQuery? I think this is Mootools framework

Comment: Site is made in Joomla and it does use Mootools also... the only js error in console I get is: TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of null

Comment: Do you actually have elements with those tagNames ?

Comment: Itay - I know, but the thing is that I don't know what buttons will be clicked and when...

Comment: adeneo - of course :)

I guess I missed something in the jQuery code or not constructed it well..

Comment: You do know that jQuery uses `#` for ID and `.` for classes, just like CSS ?

Comment: Right now you're targeting the tagName, as in -> `<size_default></size_default>`

Comment: adeneo - yes, I tried with that also, but I also have other jQuery code on site that don't have the # and . and the code looks like mine and it works fine..

Comment: Do you have both jQuery and Mootools? in jQuery in no conflict mode?

Comment: That's because it uses mootools for the selector, but that wouldn't give you a jQuery object, are you somehow using noConflict for this ?

Comment: Yep, I use jquery noconflict

Comment: Btw, next time you can tag Mootools directly when you post so all "helpers" are aware of that :) I added Mootools tag in your post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your post the `id="youtube-player"` is missing.

If you are using Mootools and jQuery can be more safe to avoid Mootools `$`.

So try this:

```
var all_spans = document.getElements('span#size_default,span#size_450,span#size_600');
document.id('size_default').addEvent('click', function () {
    all_spans.removeClass('active');
    this.addClass('active');
    document.id('youtube-player').removeClass('h_450').removeClass('h_600').addClass('h_355');
});
document.id('size_450').addEvent('click', function () {
    all_spans.removeClass('active');
    this.addClass('active');
    document.id('youtube-player').removeClass('h_355').removeClass('h_600').addClass('h_450');
});
document.id('size_600').addEvent('click', function () {
    all_spans.removeClass('active');
    this.addClass('active');
    document.id('youtube-player').removeClass('h_355').removeClass('h_450').addClass('h_600');
});
```

You can check the console in this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yy3Gr/1/)

Comment: WOW, your a genious, that really worked, I just copied and pasted your code and it works perfectly!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @AlexandruVlas, glad I could help. It's not me being genius, its Mootools being flexible :)